# How to make If Statements work simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement

Consider a `div` which is square and I have detected the centers vertically and horizontally, In `OnMouseMove` event I want to perform rotateX and rotateY on the element if from centers get close to top,left, right, bottom. I have written the code below and works nicley:

```
var CSSProperties = 
`
  transition-duration: 250ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition-property: unset;
  transform: 
`;

if (xPosition > xDivided) {
  DOMElement.style.cssText = CSSProperties + `rotateY(${xFormula}deg);`;
}

if (xPosition < xDivided) {
  DOMElement.style.cssText = CSSProperties + `rotateY(${xFormula}deg);`;
}

if (yPosition < yDivided) {
  DOMElement.style.cssText = CSSProperties + `rotateX(${yFormula}deg);`;
}

if (yPosition > yDivided) {
  DOMElement.style.cssText = CSSProperties + `rotateX(${yFormula}deg);`;
}
```

I have 2 problem:

1. With this sort of `If Statement` writing, it works only vertically not horizontal as when I remove vertically codes, It works in horizontal.
2. When mouse get close to corners It just works in horizontal or vertical not both of them.

I think my problem should be here but I can't resolve it, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Make the code choose the X and Y strings separately, and then add *both* of them to the CSS properties string at the end.

Comment: Think about it, you replace the property....

Comment: The earlier code does not work because the latter code replaces the property that the earlier code might have already changed.  Add the changes to a temp variable and add that to CSSProperties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your code overrides `DOMElement.style.cssText` inside every if statement.
So let's say the first and third if statements are true; In this case, transform will be set to `` CSSProperties + `rotateY(${xFormula}deg);` ``, only to be immediately set to `` `rotateX(${yFormula}deg);` ``, overriding the previous one. Because of the order of your if statements, in which the vertical calculation comes after the horizontal one, the vertical transform property (rotateX) will override the horizontal one (rotateY).

Instead, you can append to the end of `CSSProperties`, such that **both**
transforms are added. Then all you have to do is set `DOMElement.style.cssText` to `CSSProperties`, which contains both of your transforms.

```
var CSSProperties = 
`
  transition-duration: 250ms;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  transition-delay: 0;
  transition-property: unset;
  transform: 
`;

if (xPosition > xDivided) {
  CSSProperties += `rotateY(${xFormula}deg)`;
}

if (xPosition < xDivided) {
  CSSProperties += `rotateY(${xFormula}deg)`;
}

if (yPosition < yDivided) {
  CSSProperties += `rotateX(${yFormula}deg)`;
}

if (yPosition > yDivided) {
  CSSProperties += `rotateX(${yFormula}deg)`;
}

DOMElement.style.cssText = CSSProperties + ';';
```

Comment: did you try after my edit? I moved semicolons from the added strings to the end of the code, after the `if`s

Comment: Thanks, It works like a charm. Can you please add more description in your answer that how it works?

Comment: @AliBahaari sure!

Comment: Thanks again, Great help.